# htaccess file error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hey people i have a problem with a client host, in my host for tests and develop .htaccess and mod_rewrite works perfectly but when i put the site files in client host give me 500 ERROR. My file .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwr=$1
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

mod_rewrite is activated on client host because this works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule teste\.html http://www.amen.pt [R]
```

so like you can see in http://www.maiormaquina.com/offers give a 500 error, but in my server
http://www.amiguinhodesign.com/mm_new/offers works fine with the same .htaccess file.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message written to the Apache error log?

Comment: thats a problem because host provider dont give access to error log :s

Comment: is the htaccess file in the document root?

Comment: Get a new host provider. This is basic stuff.

Comment: yes @ /public/www/ is document root

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the problem with this .htaccess file content:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwr=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Use it :)